# PyQt5 ComboBox - how do I set the color of CurrentText without affecting the dropdown list?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

The following snippet correctly sets the colors of individual entries in the ComboBox dropdown list.  However, when an item is selected and transferred to the CurrentText field, *all* of the entries in the dropdown change to the color of CurrentText.  How do I transfer the color of an entry to be displayed as CurrentText *without* affecting the dropdown list?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class ComboDemo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        def combo_changed():
            for color in ('red', 'green', 'blue'):
                if color == cb.currentText():
                    cb.setStyleSheet('color: {}'.format(color))

        grid = QGridLayout()
        cb = QComboBox()
        grid.addWidget(cb, 0, 0)
        model = cb.model()
        for color in ('red', 'green', 'blue'):
            entry = QStandardItem(color)
            entry.setForeground(QColor(color))
            model.appendRow(entry)

        cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(combo_changed)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
c = ComboDemo()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It doesn't do that for me when i click on a item in the combo box rest of the items color won't change to the current selected item's color. I am on Windows 8, python3.6.0, pyqt5.6.0

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm on Linux, Python 3.6.5 and PyQt5 5.10-3.  Also, click on an item, close the dropdown, and re-open it.  That's when all the colors change to a single color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `QComboBox:editable`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class ComboDemo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        def combo_changed():
            for color in ('red', 'green', 'blue'):
                if color == cb.currentText():
                    cb.setStyleSheet("QComboBox:editable{{ color: {} }}".format(color))

        grid = QGridLayout()
        cb = QComboBox()
        grid.addWidget(cb, 0, 0)
        model = cb.model()
        for color in ('red', 'green', 'blue'):
            entry = QStandardItem(color)
            entry.setForeground(QColor(color))
            model.appendRow(entry)

        cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(combo_changed)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
c = ComboDemo()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: That did it - thanks!  I was tearing my hair out looking for a needle in a haystack!